# Ionic service does not run when view change

Tags: angularjs, service, ionic-framework, controller

I have a state define as :#/app/exercises/:id

This is the service to retrieve exercises from server:

```
app.factory('ExercisesService', function (ApiEndpoint, $resource, $stateParams) {
var exercises = $resource(ApiEndpoint.url + '/books/' + $stateParams.book_id + '/exercises/' + $stateParams.id);
return exercises;
});
```

And this is the controller:

```
app.controller('ExerciseCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, ExercisesService, ExerciseTemplates, $ionicHistory, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {

    var templates = ExerciseTemplates;

    ExercisesService.get(function (Exercise) {
            $scope.exercise = Exercise.exercise;
            console.log($scope.exercise);
            $scope.exercise_next = 1083;
            $scope.exercise_content = JSON.parse($scope.exercise.content);
            $scope.exercise_template = 'templates/exercise_templates/' + ExerciseTemplates[$scope.exercise.template_id - 1] + '.html';
    });
}
```

However when the :id on the link change, the controller run again but the service does not run and the view load the old exercise instead of new one. I have set cached = false both global and inside view but it changes nothing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because services in angular is always singletons. So the exercises object will always look like the first time it's created.

There is multiple ways to solve this but I suggest that your factory take the id as a pram and then pass the id to the factory from the controller when you request a object, this way the service will always return you the correct object.